# Repeating 'NAME' in a Formal Letter___

Tags: formal-language

At the end of a formal letter we always write our name, but sometimes people tend to write their names in the body of the letter as well.

Is it **superfluous** writing **name** and **other information** in the body of the letter, as we must write it at the bottom?

An example of letter:

> Dear Sir,
> With due respect, I would like to say that I, **[name],** have successfully qualified...

> Yours faithfully
> **[Name]**

Is one of the **name** superfluous?

Comment: An example of how people write their names in the body might help clarify what you're referring to

Comment: This question is not at all **clear**.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not superfluous.

Unless it is a personal letter to someone who knows you well, telling the recipient who you are provides context (if they are already acquainted with you) or at least puts your name in their mind (if you are strangers, but the letter is a job application or similar). At the end of the letter you should sign your name whether or not you included it near the beginning.

But note that most "formal" or "business" letters will contain a *letterhead design* or failing that *some area at the top of the paper* indicating the individual or organization writing the letter. (See [this image search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=formal%20letter&t=h_&iax=images&ia=images) for examples.) So restating your name in the body may not be necessary; the information is at the top of the page already.